# Error Transferring ManagedObjectContext with Core Data

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I am getting this error when using this code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Add Role Segue"])
  {
    NSLog(@"Setting RolesTVC as a delegate of AddRolesTVC");

   AddRoleTVC *addRoleTVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    addRoleTVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
  }
}
```

This code worked perfectly until I decided that I wanted to use a Table View Controller and in order for me to have a navigation bar up at the top I had to embed a navigation controller.

The error is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setManagedObjectContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

The way that I understand it is because the navigation controller is in the way and it will not transfer the managedObjectContext because the UINavigationController isn't made to take the managedObjectContext.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The segue's `destinationViewController:` method is returning a `UINavigationController`, not the `AddRoleTVC` as you expect. You should look at the view controllers that the `UINavigationController` is managing. The first one *should* be your `AddRoleTVC`.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Add Role Segue"])
  {

    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    AddRoleTVC *addRoleTVC = (AddRoleTVC *)[navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Setting RolesTVC as a delegate of AddRolesTVC");

    addRoleTVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
  }
}
```

You could make this a little more robust by (1) checking the navController actually has a viewController in the viewControllers array and (2) checking the type to ensure it's an `AddRoleTVC`.

Comment: I have this similarly in my app delegate just didn't know how to reword to make it for a UINavigationController. Thank you so much